# Changing a seperator while importing a CSV into a DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, import

I'm trying to change the seperator.
We want to change `;` to `,`

This is our import code:

```
private void Import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    fdlg.Title = "Select file";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    fdlg.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
    fdlg.Filter = "Text and CSV Files(*.txt, *.csv)|*.txt;*.csv|Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|CSV Files(*.csv)|*.csv|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFileName.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        Import();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string strFileName)
        {   

            ADODB.Connection oConn = new ADODB.Connection();
            oConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";", "", "", 0); //We have tried to change this.
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
            ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            rs.Open(strQuery, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";", //We have tried to change this.
            ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
            adapter.Fill(dt, rs);

            return dt;

}
private void Import()
{
if (txtFileName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
 {
try
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable(txtFileName.Text);
    dgvGv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dgvGv2.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dgvGv3.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
EAN       ;Product code ;Name
363738492 ;MT-01234     ;iphone case
153289234 ;MT-89854     ;samsung case
876253483 ;PO-43466     ;network cable
```

(this is an example not the actual file)

The current seperator is:   `;`
But we want it to be:  `,`

We have been looking at this code but couldn't find the seperator. 
We have also Googled a bunch.

if you have any question feel free to comment

Comment: Not really sure why you are not using [existing CSV parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c), but in your connection string you have `Delimited\";"` You can change that to `,`

Comment: do you know what this line does 
`oConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";", "", "", 0);` it's looking you right in the face..

Comment: @DJKRAZE We have tried that already before, but that gave me an error it's in dutch so I think I can't give it to you real fast. I will edit my post to show people i've already tried it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok better yet can you show what the first line in the file looks like.. a

Comment: also looks like your connection string is incorrect 
take a look at this as well http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Comment: @DJKRAZE other than the sepperator we have no problems

Comment: just change the last part of the connection for the delim to read as the following 
`oConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";");`

Comment: I also have a posting that I have put out on `SO` a while back that works take a look at this as well [Add CSV Connection to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835828/add-csv-connection-to-excel-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @DJKRAZE first of all, i'm a friend of sjors we are working on this together. we have tried your code with: `FMT=Delimited\";");` , this gives us no error but a stange thing is that the actual delimiter is: `,` because if we import the example file with `;` it doesn't work

Comment: @DJKRAZE what we also would like to add is a textbox so like this 
`FMT=Delimited\"" + txtDelimiter.Text + "");`

Comment: if have read somewhere that maybe using 64bit gives the error.

Comment: We still haven't found out what the issue is... I guess I just go and try searching somemore. Thanks for trying to help me out!